# \textgreek command unknown with LuaLaTeX since last babel-greek update

Tags: luatex, babel, greek, babel-greek

Since the last `babel-greek` package update (around 2020-11-10), the `\textgreek` command is no longer defined while compiling with LuaLaTeX. The following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,french]{babel}
\begin{document}
\foreignlanguage{greek}{\textgreek{da'imwn}}
\end{document}
```

produces, while compiling with LuaLaTeX:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \textgreek 
           {da'imwn}
```

Though it worked fine before the `babel-greek` update (and works fine with the package reverted to the previous version) but it still compiles fine with pdfLaTeX and the latest version of `babel-greek`:

[image: result]

How can I get `\textgreek` to work with LuaLaTeX and the latest version of `babel-greek`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

greek no longer loads LGR if it detects an unicode engine. But you can do it yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,TU]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,french]{babel}
\begin{document}
\foreignlanguage{greek}{\textgreek{da'imwn}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still load the LGR encoding with `luainputenc` and define `\textgreek` to run `\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont`.  This will hopelessly confuse the hyphenation patterns, however.  It will only work if you declare 8-bit LGR fonts with the same family names as your Unicode fonts, for example by loading `substitutefont` and declaring `\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF}`, or by loading `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[NFSSFamily=Tempora-TLF]`.

You asked about LuaLaTeX, but XeTeX gives you the option of defining a font mapping.  Your question inspired me to make one up for beta code, a more standardized way to encode Greek in ASCII, which currently is supported only for PDFTeX with `betababel`.